# How to enable emulator control in android device monitor

Tags: android-studio

[image]This is my screen shot of my problem which am facing. Help me to enable this emulator control in android device monitor.so can you help me with the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable telnet client on your computer.

If you are windows user follow this step:

1.go to control panel

2.go to programs and features

3.click on "turn windows feature on or off" a prompt box will be appear()

4.mark the checkbox of Telnet Client

5.open command prompt and type "telnet localhost port_number" (see [cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C25Vw.png) image) after this connection will be establish.

device monitor in android studio only works for the default emulators. It does not work for genymotion or mobile device.